# Can I bring fruit from Mexico into Düsseldorf airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany

I'm traveling in Mexico and would love to take some papayas (2-3) and mangos (3-4) from Mexico on my flight from Cancun, Mexico to Düsseldorf, Germany to bring home.

On the customs page of Düsseldorf Airport I can't find anything specific about fruits and I know some countries don't allow fruits if you cross the border overland (sometimes even within the same country). The website states more of alcohol, cigarettes, meat, milk products and so on. I also have a transfer in Manchester and I will put these fruits in my carry-on.

Can anyone guarantee if I can or cannot bring the fruits in, since I don't want to buy them to have them throw away after the flight.

Comment: ASFAIK you need to provide a 'Pflanzengesundheitszeugnis'. Even for private imports. You can request one at https://www.pgz-online.de/ . But i dont think it is worth the trouble and money.

Comment: @Hyarus I think this is applicable to plants and plant products (like seeds) rather than food. I really do not think it is applicable in this case.

Comment: @MJeffryes After a quick search I found this document from the Frankfurt Airport(Pflanzenschutz) [PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiN5c29nZzcAhXqIMAKHfOgCmcQFghCMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.frankfurt-airport.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fairport%2FDokumente%2FGep%25C3%25A4ck%2FInformationen%2520zur%2520Einfuhr%2520von%2520Pflanzen.pdf%2F_jcr_content%2Frenditions%2Foriginal.media_file.download_attachment.file%2FInformationen%2520zur%2520Einfuhr%2520von%2520Pflanzen.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0p0OZP6zwqalP1THP4q0Od). In which Fruits are listed as prohibited.

Comment: @Hyarus This is confusing, since it doesn't really square with this information: http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Food-and-feed/food-and-feed_node.html . Incidentally, here is the English version of that document http://pflanzenschutzdienst.rp-giessen.de/fileadmin/dokumente/pflanzenbeschau/BIOSECURITY_ON_INT_FLIGHTS_e5_Druck_doppelseitig.pdf

Comment: @MJeffryes This information is more specific: http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Animals-and-plants-products-containing-animal-or-vegetable-substance/Plant-protection/plant-protection.html I think this is the answer but i will dig into it

Comment: @Hyarus Yes, I think this is correct, but it is very confusing that the other page doesn't mention any issues with bringing in plant products other than potatoes and mushrooms! Very poorly organised information.

Comment: I can tell you that I wasn't allowed to bring Mexican grapes into the United States via land from Canada, so there is a high probability that there is a restriction of casual imports of Mexican fruit into the E.U.  You certainly won't get in trouble bringing the fruit, as long as you declare it, but you may have it seized if it's not allowed.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie The USA has significantly more strict biosecurity rules than most of the EU, and is completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From Germany's customs agency](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Animals-and-plants-products-containing-animal-or-vegetable-substance/Plant-protection/plant-protection_node.html) (emphasis added):

> If you intend to bring living plants, parts of plants (cut flowers, for example), **fruits**, or seeds to Germany, or to order them from a non-EU country and receive them by post, you should observe the following notes and import restrictions. By doing so you will avoid endangering our Nature and our crops.
>
> Import/Mail from Asian, American, or African states, or from Australia
>
> Imports from these countries always require a phytosanitary certificate from the country of origin of the plants, parts of plants, or plant products.

That does say "by post" (though "Import/Mail" seems to cover all forms of imports) so it's possible more leniency could be offered at the airport, but there's no guarantee of that. Since you won't have a phytosanitary certificate for a handful of personal imports, this would indicate the fruits are prohibited. You could declare them and see whether they're allowed in anyway, but given that the website says paperwork is required that you won't have, that's far from a guarantee they won't be destroyed.

Comment: Since I will have a transfer in Manchester. Doesn't it mean I will enter Germany from a European country regarding import laws, but I will have to look into the import laws of Manchester for importing from Mexico? Even though I don't exit the airport and only transit?

Comment: @Lewis The import laws apply to the source of the product, not to the country you enter through. But you are right, you will probably go through costums in Manchester (which allow [up to 2kg fruits](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports#food-from-outside-the-eu-details-of-restrictions)). But due to the fact that you are only transiting, will the officers probably tell you to decleare them on arraival in Germany (where they get dumped).

Answer (score -1):

There is no explicit rule forbidding the private import of fruit in hand lugagge to the EU. There is no need to declare them either. 
To avoid misunderstandings carry them in your hand luggages.

Comment: Do you have a citation showing that there's no need to declare them?

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie  I explicitely said "hand luggage" - By my personal experience and numerous other in "german" speaking discussion there are never any problems with common fruits in hand luggage.

Comment: I'd still like to see a citation from an official site.  Is it that officers rarely check, or that if they do check, it is never a problem?  There is a huge difference between the two.

Comment: Hand luggage and carry on luggage are both carried through customs together. Therefor it does not matter where you carry your fruit, it will be in your possession when you go through customs.